# Makefile only tracks the first file

Tags: c++, makefile

There are two .cpp files in my makefile:

```
test1.o : test1.cpp
        g++ test1.cpp -o test1.o

test2.o : test2.cpp
        g++ test2.cpp -o test2.o
```

After I make changes to both test1.cpp and test2.cpp and type `make` in the command line, only `test1.o` is recompiled, and nothing is done to `test2.o`.

However, if I swap the two blocks in the makefile, `test2.o` will be recompiled automatically and `test1.o` will not.

It seems like my makefile only keeps track of the first file. I wonder which part goes wrong.

Comment: You probably want a `-c` flag on those because they are just building the objects and not linking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `make` will build the first thing in the makefile, if you don't tell it what to build.

You can either run `make test1.o test2.o` to make both specifically, or add a fake target so it will make `all` by default - this is what many makefiles 
use.

Using `.PHONY` tells Make that `all` isn't a real file, so it doesn't misbehave just in case you have a file called `all` for some reason.

```
all: test1.o test2.o
.PHONY: all
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a default target. A really simple starting point: `all: test1.o test2.o`